# using background-position to spread background accross multiple items

Tags: jquery, background-image, css-sprites, background-position

So I am working what should be a nifty effect.  I have a bunch of `li`'s of height 40px.  I want a background image to display so that the top 40px is the background for the first `li`, the next 40px is the background for the second one... etc etc...

currently it will only show the top section of the image, I cannot get bgCount to increment... Any suggestions?

```
        var bgCount = 0;
        $('li').each(function(i) {                
           $(this).css('background-image', 'url(forground.jpg)');
           $(this).css('background-position', '0px' + bgCount + 'px');
           bgCount += 40;
        });
```

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yZDDK/4/

Comment: In your JSFiddle, make sure to create the selectors to match the selectors you are searching for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a space

```
       $(this).css('background-position', '0px ' + bgCount + 'px');
                                              ^
```

Answer (score 0):

JS Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wz2qx/5/